# open source Video Conferencing MCU intergration with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, video-conferencing

I want to run a video conferencing server which can handle 10 party video conference calls(each person should see all the others and himself on their softphone or IP-phone). I tried doing this on asterisk10 using confbridge, but my conference room did not stream video.Audio worked fine.

I looked into bigbluebutton but I do not want any webconferencing solution.
I looked into openvcs but cant make it work as I dont seem to understand the working.

So is there any MCU out there I can intergrate with asterisk to handle my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the mcu media server for video conferencing solution

you can get the application related info here http://www.medooze.com/products/mcu.aspx

Comment: Hi, I had been testing diastar with asterisk for the last month. They have a good solution but it lacks HD conferencing.

Comment: Great, Thanks for your comment I ll be trying same in few days

Answer (score 0):

Now freeswitch has full featured video conference with MCU. I have tested system with lifesize hardware and browser based phone and sip client. It works fine